# Error 400: Invalid Value, invalid

Tags: android, go, google-play

Trying to troubleshoot unit tests written against [go-iap](https://github.com/dogenzaka/go-iap/blob/master/playstore/validator.go#L75) and I'm having a hard time.

When using VerifyProduct() I'm getting googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Value, invalid, this is with the receipt contract provided in the unit tests that shipped with the library and the *only* change being modification from packageName to my package name (which I am pretty sure is a valid package name).

Steps I've taken so far:
I've verified the token permissions are set correctly to Finance, configured the service account.

I believe that this token is working as my test gives me the same results the passing unit test gave with the same contract, but with my own package it throws a 400. What could be wrong with my package name that the api is returning an invalid value for it?

Comment: Without more details hard to comment, however response code 400 means you have bad argument(s), i.e. maybe the problem is not in your package name. Are product ID and a token required? If so, are they correct?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly without any other tests to look at or any other information to troubleshoot available, I switched to a different solution that I got working instead. There just wasn't enough information to work with, I posted this question in the hopes that someone had experienced this in the past and had easily hopped over it. I don't know where the particular black hole of information is, but I'm suspecting it's play store api.

I believe this is most likely an artifact of go-iap using the oauth2 authentication mechanism, and something I either had missed setting up or misconfigured was causing a problem. The node validator only uses the public key and  purchase signature and it worked pretty much right out of the box. This really surprised me as I thought that oauth was required. This is my first time working with the payment gateways, and I'm still trying to figure out what can even go wrong, and when the error messages are *this* cryptic, it's a real uphill battle.